# ¿Cómo utilizo un archivo de configuración .json para decidir qué elementos se importan a mi librería?

Tags: javascript, json, sass, librería

Buen día chicos/as. Tengo una duda un poco complicada.

Estoy creando una librería con **Sass** y **JavaScript** (también con Gulp.js) donde se encuentran distintos componentes (por ejemplo: diálogos, botones...) que poseen su archivo .scss y .js.

Lo que intento hacer es tener un archivo de configuración donde el usuario decida qué elementos quiere que incluya el archivo ya compilado.

Por ejemplo: Tengo un archivo ***lib-config.json*** en la raíz del directorio con este contenido:

```
// - lib-config.json
{
    "imports": {
        "dialog": true,
        "button": false
    }
}
```

Este debería importar solo los elementos de `"dialog"` y dejaría a `"button"` por fuera.

Ahora la pregunta, ¿qué tecnología debería utilizar? ¿Existe algún PlugIn de Gulp.js que haga esto?

Comment: En el archivo gulpfile pues añadir tareas de compilación donde decides que archivos vas a compilar.